# Engine backfired and blew this part to pieces. Please identify so I can source out a replacement. See notes on photo

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, express-van

[image: photo of part needed]

Please identify so I can source out a replacement. See notes on photo.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As long as it is not completely destroyed and you can find it, the part number *should* be stamped into the plastic. Clean up the parts and see if you can find it.

Comment: tell the complete vehicle identity (VIN) and other details like make, model, variant etc.

Answer (score 4):

looks like air resonator.

[image]

https://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Chevy-Express-3500-03-19-Engine-Air-Intake-Resonator-Chamber-GM-Original-/283656815700

number 16 in the link below

[image]
https://www.ebay.com/itm/GM-OEM-Air-Cleaner-Rear-Intake-Duct-Tube-Hose-15270558/202924783543?fits=Model%3AExpress+2500%7CMake%3AChevrolet&epid=659531762&hash=item2f3f4277b7:g:fzsAAOSwXY5ZQzh8